# Need IME composed text to commit after swype is complete

Tags: android, input, android-softkeyboard

thanks for any help up front.  I will admit ahead of time that my Java is still immature, so I feel like I'm in over my head.  I've been searching almost all day for this answer and trying various approaches to no avail.

I am using a commercial game engine which exports a game to an Eclipse project with a GLSurfaceView class implementation.  They have a hook to send single key codes into the game engine for key down and key up events, and I want to use those hooks to send keys from the Android keyboard (soft or hard).

Overriding the view.onKeyUp, onKeyDown, and onKeyMultiple interfaces allows me to get almost everything I'm looking to do, but when an IME like Swype is used, I still have one remaining problem.

When I swype the word, it shows up in the floating window (I believe swype is drawing this), but then it doesn't come across in the onKeyUp, onKeyDown, or onKeyMultiple callbacks.  If I hit space or any other letter on the keyboard, I then get the onKeyMultiple callback which sends the string I swyped previously.

I thought I could just call finishComposingText() in my own InputConnection, so I overrode the View.onCreateInputConnection method in the GLSurfaceView class, and then called finishComposingText() in the DrawFrame() method for the game engine, and it worked somewhat.  It actually immediately sent the text through the onKeyMultiple callback, but then if I hit a key, it sent the same text again, duplicating it in my "3D edit box".  I also didn't like the idea of calling that every frame.

I'm just completely lost on what approach I should take to get the swype results to show up instantly after I swype without having to press a key.  The game engine is not using a TextView or similar Android widget, so I tried the following as well with no luck:

```
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection ( EditorInfo outAttrs )
{
    outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ;
    outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_NULL;
    oInputC = new BaseInputConnection ( this, false ) ;
    return oInputC;
}
```

oInputC is just a static variable I can use to call the finishComposingText() method.

Could anyone suggest an approach or reference?  I have found only a couple of other questions like this, and they were both unanswered.  It seems not many people are creating their own text edit boxes and need to implement the backend for them, but that's essentially what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing the same issue, but I think I have found solution.
I was checking android source code of TextView and EditableInputConnection to see how they are doing: it turns out that's its not so easy.

I think I managed to make it work correctly, with my custom editor. This is how my input connection looks like.

```
    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs)
    {
        outAttrs.actionLabel = "";
        outAttrs.hintText = "";
        outAttrs.initialCapsMode = 0;
        outAttrs.initialSelEnd = outAttrs.initialSelStart = -1;
        outAttrs.label = "";
        outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED | EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI;        
        outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT;        
        final InputConnection in = new BaseInputConnection(this, false){
        private HudInputElement getInputElement(){...}
            @Override
        public boolean setComposingText(CharSequence text,
                int newCursorPosition) {
            B2DEngine.getLogger().info("composing text: "+text+","+newCursorPosition);
            HudInputElement input = getInputElement();
            if(input!=null){
                input.setComposingText(text.toString());
            }
            return super.setComposingText(text, newCursorPosition);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean finishComposingText() {
            HudInputElement input = getInputElement();
            if(input!=null){
                input.doneComposing();
            }
            return super.finishComposingText();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean commitText(CharSequence text, int newCursorPosition) {
            B2DEngine.getLogger().info("commit:"+text.toString()+","+this.getEditable().toString());
            HudInputElement input = getInputElement();
            if(input!=null){
                input.doneComposing();
            }
            return super.commitText(text, newCursorPosition);
        }           
        };       

        return in;
    }
```

Since soft input keyboards supports all sorts of way to autocomplete text, currently entered word is treated differently. You have to ensure that when setComposingText is called, you have to replace the text that was previously received. Only clear this `flag` when user presses a button or finishComposingText or commitText are called.

P.S. Don't forget to test other keyboards on the market.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it is exactly I needed for starting to work on a problem I have.

Comment: Good luck :) My final solution is 4 times longer + a lot for actual ui element responding to events and handling selection.

Comment: Indeed, I am doing a lot of changes to get the expected behaviour for my solution but this was a very good start point ;)